# IE9 css url modifies itself

Tags: php, html, url

I use multiple stylesheets are are included in stylesheet.php file, for example:

```
<link href="<?php print DOMAIN;?>/site/styles/correct.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I then include this in the  of the page with:

```
<?php include(HOME.'site/files/stylesheets.php');?>
```

The styles are file in IE8, FireFox and Chrome but for some reason are dropped in IE9. Looking at the network analysis the URL is different compared to the other browsers, there is no if statements changing the use of stylesheets for IE9, anyone any ideas?

Comment: Please be more specific. I will need to have more information in order to provide an answer. How exactly did the URL change? What are the urls to both of the PHP files? What are values of the constants DOMAIN and HOME?

Comment: @Stratus3D the URL changes 
From in IE8:
/improve/site/styles/style.css

IE9:
/improve/info/19/site/styles/style.css

It adds further locations in the structure.
The same code is used in in both, I don't get the change.